# Streaming audio from a PyAudio stream to be played on a webpage in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, web-audio-api, pyaudio

I'm trying to take an audio stream from my computer using PyAudio (specifically the pyaudiowpatch fork), stream that audio data over a websocket (using the [websockets library](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), and play it on a web page using javascript. To do this, I have the following Python code on the server side:

```py
import pyaudiowpatch as pyaudio

import asyncio
from websockets.server import serve


CHUNK_SIZE = 512


async def main():
    with pyaudio.PyAudio() as p:
        # 23 is the index of the device i'm trying to get the data from
        audio_device = p.get_device_info_by_index(23)
        with p.open(
            format=pyaudio.paInt16,
            channels=audio_device["maxInputChannels"],
            rate=int(audio_device["defaultSampleRate"]),
            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK_SIZE,
            input=True,
            input_device_index=audio_device["index"]
        ) as stream:
            async def handler(ws):
                print(f"Connection from {ws}")
                while stream.is_active():
                    chunk = stream.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
                    await ws.send(chunk)
                    print(f"Sent chunk to {ws}")
                print(f"Closing connection to {ws}")

            async with serve(handler, host="localhost", port=8081):
                print("Listening...")
                await asyncio.Future()

asyncio.run(main())
```

This code works fine, and when I make a connection from the web page, the data is sent over just fine. My client-side js is as follows:

```js
const host = "ws://localhost:8081"
const ws = new WebSocket(host, "testProtocol")
const audioContext = new AudioContext()
const source = audioContext.createBufferSource()

source.connect(audioContext.destination)

document.getElementById("playButton").onclick = () => {
    source.start()
}

ws.onmessage = (event) => {
    event.data.arrayBuffer().then(data => {
        console.log(new Uint8Array(data)) // Shows that the data being received matches that being sent
        audioContext.decodeAudioData(new Uint8Array(data).buffer, (buffer) => {
            source.buffer = buffer
        })
    })
}
```

The idea is that the ws client receives the data as a blob, and then turns it into an ArrayBuffer to be played by the Web Audio API. However, I get the following error from the js: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains an unknown content type.` Clearly this means that the audio data I am passing is not in a format that the Web Audio API can understand.

What is the correct way to play the audio being streamed over to the web page?

Comment: i have a solution for you, i've been working on it for some time, its actually in node.js but im sure it would easily be converted serverside, hit me up on stackoverflow chat if you want discuss further https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript